# Grails Spring DSL Not Setting String Properties

Tags: spring, grails

2 simple String properties on my Service:

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = false

    def uri1
    def uri2
}
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    myService(com.myapp.MyService) {
        uri1 = 'http://my.endpoint1.com'
        uri2 = 'http://my.endpoint2.com'
    }
}
```

And.. Both properties remain null.  Seems simple and obvious enough, but little to go on and I seem to be explicitly following the doc and some posts I've found.. Any ideas?  Thanks.

I've tried typing the properties as String, def, static String.. nothing helps.
I've tried using bean -> in the properties closure and bean.str1 etc... nothing helps.

**UPDATE:**
The goal is simply to set these string properties on the Service class via Spring.  Yes, using Config.groovy is an option, but that requires an extra step of accessing the config.. which I find to be an unnecessary hoop to jump through in this case.  After all, Spring is being used, so why not use it.  In my case they happen to be URI's (updated example code).

See: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html 14.3, for example.
Where `driverClassName = "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"` is set on a dataSource registration.  I tried adding java-style setters and getters to the Service class, still null

Comment: OK I got it working with constructor injection, based on http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html - 'Using Constructor Arguments' . Still curious if anyone has an idea why the property-injection technique isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going nuts, this should work exactly as you think it should.

I've prepared an example project to confirm this over on [github](https://github.com/gid79/so-q8548146-spring-dsl):

https://github.com/gid79/so-q8548146-spring-dsl

I prepared the example with grails 1.3.4, which just happened to be the version I have installed locally, it's been a little while since I used it.

It is possible that you have stumbled onto a bug in the version you are using, your references are to 1.0.x documentation, which version are you using?

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarifying (I was indeed starting to question my sanity ;)  I'm using 1.4.0.M1, should have mentioned that.  And... doh!  OK your test code worked exactly as I thought it would.. so I took a fresh look over my code, everything is the same.. EXCEPT I'm running unit tests here.. and in my unit case.. I was new-ing up the Service test target by hand.. and yep, i realized that means no DI, so no Spring setting the properties.  Refactoring to have the service be a member of the test class, and life is good!  Thanks for the help, the fresh perspective got me there, eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the overall goal.

resources.groovy can be used to define beans. MyService because will be automatically 'injected' by grails everywhere, so you can access it just by:

```
def myService
```

Then you can call methods on myService, typically in your controller.

If you are trying to define 'application settings' then Config.groovy is where I understand it should go:

```
icooeee {
  defaultCategory = "lifestyle"
}
```

And read this in grails controllers, services etc:

```
ConfigurationHolder.config.icooeee.defaultCategory
```

If you wanted to initialise a bean - java object that is defined src/java, in a plugin or library. Then constructor arguments make sense, as per the grails documentation you are talking about: http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html

The MVC/domain driven design does say that grails domain objects should maintain data and logic relating to the data. Therefore, consider this when maintaining state relating to services.

I have successfully configured beans for apache-camel in resources.groovy. Note that these are initialising the underlying apache camel objects, not grails objects which are normally provided 'for free':

```
case "development":
  jmsConnectionFactoryLocal(org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = 'vm://localhost'
  }

  _jmsConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnectionFactory) {
    brokerURL = ConfigurationHolder.config.caller.activemqServer
  }

  jmsConnectionFactory(org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory) {
    connectionFactory = ref('_jmsConnectionFactory')
  }

  jmsConfig(org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration) {
    connectionFactory = ref('_jmsConnectionFactory')
    transacted = true
    concurrentConsumers = 10
  }

  activemqServer(org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent) {
    configuration = ref('jmsConfig')
  }
  break
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, though the goal should be quite obvious, adding more detail above-

Comment: Also, what state is maintained in domain objects, or how the service will be injected into, say, a controller, is all pretty much irrelevant here - we're just talking about how the DSL configures Spring to instantiate the bean as configured.  Telling Spring to simply assign these string values to said properties is pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Bobby - this might be it. No autowiring if you define the object in resources.groovy http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Services-defined-in-resources-groovy-do-not-get-other-services-automatically-injected-td3496413.html. Therefore, bean.autowire = 'byName'

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but that's only when you define a bean in resources (directly with Spring) and want another service auto-injected into it.. you'd need to be more intimate with Spring there, not what's going on in my case.  Turns out it was how my Service class was being constructed in the test class.  It, itself, needs to be instantiated by DI in order for its dependencies to be injected.  Since I was 'newing' it up myself in the test methods, Spring/grails had no chance to perform injection on it.  Thanks anyway :)